# C: Initializing struct variables after declaration

Tags: c++, c

I encountered this recently but could not figure out why the language would allow b = c; below and fail b = {3, 4}. Is there an issue with allowing the latter ?

```
struct T {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    T a = {1, 2};
    T b;

    b = {3, 4}; // why does this fail ?

    T c = {3, 4};
    b = c; // this works

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I knew this **is** a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16614045/694576

Comment: @alk, this is not exactly a dup. The other link talks about assigning a struct to a struct while this one is only about assigning an initializer to a struct.

Comment: `b = {3, 4};` is not an initialisation, but an assignment. The former would be `T b = {3, 4};`. Yes, those two are different beasts ... :-) Initialisation happens during definition. Assignment happens in all other cases.

Comment: So to answer you questions title: Because this is by definition! ;-)

Comment: The title was slightly different from the content and hence changed it to match the detailed description. Does it still look like a dup now ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It fails because `{3, 4}`, though it's a valid initializer, is not an expression (at least it isn't in C; see below for more about C++).

Every expression in C has a type that can be determined by examining the expression itself. `{3, 4}` could potentially be of type `struct T`, or `int[2]` (an array type), or any of a myriad of other types.

C99 added a new feature called *compound literals* that use a similar syntax to initializers, but let you specify the type, creating an expression:

```
b = (struct T){3, 4};
```

Note that the `(struct T)` is *not* a cast operator; it's part of the syntax of a compound literal.

For more information on compound literals, see section 6.5.2.5 of the [draft C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Compound literals were introduced by the 1999 ISO C standard (C99). If your compiler doesn't support C99 or better (*cough*Microsoft*cough*), then you won't be able to use them.

If you're using C++ (which, don't forget, is a different language), it doesn't support compound literals, but there may be an alternative. As Potatoswatter points out in a comment, this:

```
b = T{3, 4};
```

is valid in C++11 (but not in earlier versions of the C++ language). This is covered in section 5.2.3 [expr.type.conf] of the C++ standard.

For that matter, this:

```
b = {3, 4};
```

is also valid C++11 syntax. This form can be used in a number of specified contexts, including the right side of an assignment. This is covered in section 8.5.4 [dcl.init.list] of the C++ standard.

One recent draft of the C++ standard is N3485.

(g++ supports C99-style compound literals in C++ as an extension.)

And if you're stuck with a pre-C99 compiler, you can always write your own initialization function, such as:

```
struct T init_T(int x, int y) {
    struct T result;
    result.x = x;
    result.y = y;
    return result;
}

/* ... */

struct T obj;
/* ... */
obj = init_T(3, 4);
```

It's an annoying amount of extra work (which is why C99 added compound literals), but it does the job. On the other hand, in most cases you're probably better off using initialization:

```
struct T obj;
/* ... */
{
    struct T tmp = { 3, 4 };
    obj = tmp;
}
```

Which is better probably depends on how your program is structured.

Comment: In C++, the parenthesized type-id a la cast notation is illegal, but `T{ 3, 4 }` does the trick.

Comment: Interesting. Why does the compiler process the initialization and the assignment differently ? While initializing it seems to interpret the RHS as a struct while in the assignment it is not sure ?

Comment: @user1952500: As I said, it's because `{3, 4}` is a valid initializer, which gets its type from the object being initialized, but it's not a valid expression.

Comment: Ah, I didn't pay attention to the terminology. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: that is not valid c++11 syntax. You must drop the parens around the type. This is even more severe because the syntax that was used in the question *is* valid C++11.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Thanks for catching that; I've updated my answer.

Comment: @user1952500 It would be completely trivial to make this work; it's just that the development of C is in the hands of nincompoops. I mean, you have an expression on the left of an assigment, right? It has a static type (some kind of struct). Just take the curly braced thing on the right and treat it as data of that type. Doh! We don't have to do this, after all: `i = (int) 0; f = (double) 0; p = (char *) 0`. We just use `i = 0; f = 0; p = 0`.  I cannot conclude that what C99 implements is a "compound literal". Literals do not have to be told what their type is (except to override some default)

Comment: @Kaz: We don't have to write `i = (int)0;` because `0` is already of type `int`; we don't have to write `f = (double)0;` because `0` is of a type that's implicitly convertible to `double`. But now that C++ has (just recently) permitted initializers in certain limited contexts, perhaps a future version of C will add something similar. (Your remark about "nincompoops" is unworthy of further comment.)

Comment: Note how Keith is waffling in the comment above. My three examples also include `p = 0`, where `0` is not of a type that is implicitly convertible to `char *`. What's going on is that `0` is a **kind** of thing, that is not a type, which denotes a null pointer constant (in a context-dependent way), and that's what makes it work, not (simply) a type conversion. Similarly, `{ 1, 2 }` could be a kind of thing (not necessarily a type) which, in a given context, converts to a struct typed value.

Comment: @Kaz: No, I didn't specifically mention null pointer constants. Yes, the language *could* be defined so that `{ 1, 2 }` could be used as an expression in some (but not all) contexts; C++11 shows one way to do that. (Defining the storage duration for the object, if any, associated with such an expression is non-trivial.) Such a change has not yet been made for C. I think the C standard committee is understandably hesitant to add new features and special-case rules to the standard. C99 adoption was much slower than C89/C90 adoption. Adding too many new features risks repeating that.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Consider this program on here: http://ideone.com/lrbbB4. how following 2 statements are different?

b=Test{15,30};

c={11,4}; in the program mentioned in link. Is it uses aggregate/list/uniform initialization?

Answer (score 6):

Because you didn't use the correct C99 or C11 'compound literal' notation:

```
b = (struct T){ 3, 4 };
```

See §6.5.2 **Postfix operators** and §6.5.2.5 **Compound literals** in ISO/IEC 9899:2011 for more information (amongst other places).

> `( type-name ) { initializer-list }`
>   `( type-name ) { initializer-list , }`

Comment: @JackCColeman: As the first sentence says: it's a C99 "compound literal". Microsoft still implements C89 (i.e. from 24 years ago).

Comment: @JackCColeman: since, as MSalters said, the Microsoft C compiler is a C89 compiler, there is no surprise to learning that it does not support this feature from C99. Indeed, one of the reasons for citing the standard (the old standard, be it noted, not even the current standard) was to let people who are aware of the problems with MSVC (that it is a C89 compiler, not a C99 or C11 compiler) know that it would not work with it.  I don't choose to castigate MS every time I write an answer that needs C99 or later; I don't have enough time and it won't achieve anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's the definition of the language... I don't think there is any particular reason other than "it makes it harder to write the compiler to allow for this".

You could do `b = T{3, 4}` if you have a C++ 11 compiler.

Comment: C++ doesn't support compound literals. When I try to use one with `g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic`, I get "warning: ISO C++ forbids compound-literals".

Comment: That's what I wrote to begin with, but thought I had it wrong, so changed it when I saw the other answers... Trust your instincts...